# How to replace a list of special characters in a csv in python

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas

I have some csv files that may or may not contain characters like “”à that are undesirable, so I want to write a simple script that will feed in a csv and feed out a csv (or its contents) with those characters replaced with more standard characters, so in the example:

```
bad_chars = '“”à'
good_chars = '""a'
```

The problem so far is that my code seems to produce a csv with perhaps the wrong encoding? Any help would be appreciated in making this simpler and/or making sure my output csv doesn't force an incorrect regex encoding--maybe using pandas?

Attempt:

```
import csv, string
upload_path = sys.argv[1]
input_file = open('{}'.format(upload_path), 'rb')
upload_csv = open('{}_fixed.csv'.format(upload_path.strip('.csv')), 'wb')
data = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(upload_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
in_chars = '\xd2\xd3'
out_chars = "''"
replace_list = string.maketrans(in_chars, out_chars)

for line in input_file:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = line.translate(replace_list)
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
upload_csv.close()
```

Comment: Not a directl solution to the problem you posed, but take a look at the unidecode library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.9 -- it converts non-ascii characters to ascii approximations (smart quotes to straight quotes, etc).

Answer (score 1):

As you stamped your question with the `pandas` tag - here is a pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
   .replace(r'RegEx_search_for_str', r'RegEx_replace_with_str', regex=True)
   .to_csv('/path/to/fixed.csv', index=False)
)
```

Comment: Why not calling str.translate against the df ?

Comment: @Boud, because `.str.` methods can be applied only on one column, so i would have to do something like `df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.translate(...))`

Comment: Ok I see you coming on the translate perf loop vs regex replace